# Take substring and remove period in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string for example : `192.168.22.13`
I want to take a substring and remove the periods such that I get `2213` only from this string which i can use as a custom port number.

Is there anyway I can do this in a single bash command instead of doing:

```
e1=${1//.}
e1Port=${e1:6}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` string directives don't allow nested expressions.

You may use `awk` for a single command:

```
s='192.168.22.13'
port=$(awk -F '.' '{print $3 $4}' <<< "$s")
echo "$port"
```

```
2213
```